# Ansible SSL certificate failed- urlopen error

Tags: ssl-certificate, mac-osx, ansible

I try to run ansible-playbook from OSX that run this task and I'm getting the error bellow
I tried to run 'Install Certificates.command' from Python folder but it didn't solve my problem.

```
fatal: [XXX]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://XXX.XXX.com/rest/api/2/cluster/zdu/state"}
```

```
tasks:
   - name: get Cluster state
     uri:
      url: https://{{ base_url }}.xxx.com/rest/api/2/cluster/zdu/state
      headers:
       Content-Type: application/json
      force_basic_auth: true
```

please assist.

Answer (score 2):

As show [in the official documentation page of URI module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html), you have to use the `validate_certs: no` parameter in order to disable SSL check.

In addition, your task says `force_basic_auth: true` which means you want to give authentication credentials throught HTTP Header, thing you don't actually do ;)